# How to bridge the compile time configuration and factory pattern when different sample that link to the same lib needs different impl?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, macros

I am providing a type erased interface to others, which goes like:

```cpp
class Interface{
public:
    virtual int doSomething() = 0;
}

template <typename Repository>
class InterfaceImpl {
public:
    int doSomething() override {
        return repository_->doOtherThing();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Repository> repository_;
};
```

And a factory class that hide these type stuff from caller.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Interface> factory(int type){
    switch(type){
        case 1: return std::make_unique<InterfaceImpl<SQLiteRepository>>();
        case 2: return std::make_unique<InterfaceImpl<DummyRepository>>();
        // omitted ...
    }
}
```

The `type` is actually something that read from configuration file, and is actually a string or something, i just use `int` to simplify the code here.

Everything works fine until yesterday. My boss told me: "Hey rookie, you need to hoist the `Repository` configuration stage from runtime to compile time. You should not compile the `RepositoryImpl` that will not used at runtime, since the decision can be determined at compile time and will not change in the whole application's lifecycle. Our CI pipeline's compile time is slow enough, please don't append more shit to it".

To maintain the current API that exposed to user, a natural solution that comes to my mind is change the `switch` conditions to some `#ifdef` directives and add some corresponding definitions in the cmake file, like:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Interface> factory(){
#ifdef USE_SQLITE
        return std::make_unique<InterfaceImpl<SQLiteRepository>>();
#elif defined(USE_DUMMY)
        return std::make_unique<InterfaceImpl<DummyRepository>>();
        // omitted ...
}
```

Now the tricky issue occurs: Our projects CMakeLists contains many examples & tests, like below:

```
- project
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - include
    - project
      - lib.hpp
  - src
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - lib.cpp
  - samples
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - sampleA
      - CMakeLists.txt
      - main.cpp
    - sampleB
      - CMakeLists.txt
      - main.cpp
  - tests
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - testlib.cpp
```

Some of them needs different `Repository`, for example, the sampleA might use `SQLite` while sampleB using the `Dummy`. These samples needs to link the lib that generated by src/*. And whether these different sample should be compiled can be controlled by some cmake options.

That makes the `factory` thing hard to adopt, since i cannot both return `RepositoryA` and `RepositoryB` through this functions.

one possible solution is to directly expose the `InterfaceImpl` to the API use side, so the `#ifdef` stuffs can be adopted. However, directly expose these is the thing that we don't want initially.

Any advices is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand the last part. If you select the relevant implementations via macros, you can simply keep the old factory function's signature and disable the unused cases. Or do I misunderstand what exactly "_you need to hoist the Repository configuration stage from runtime to compile time._" is supposed to mean?

Comment: @user17732522 They just want the unused cases should not be compile at all

Comment: It seems like want something to create two `liblib.a` with different macro defined when you link to different test examples. I'm not expert of cmake, but maybe my recap would help some experts to answer it. Please clarify if I'm wrong.

Comment: @LouisGo Thanks for your reply, it is a valid solution. However i personally think that it has a critical drawbacks that one needs to compile many libs version to satisfied different corresponding sample.

Comment: Re-read your question. " You should not compile the RepositoryImpl that will not used at runtime" this statement is contradict to your test. If you need `DummyRepository` in test, then it's *needed* in runtime. I am not sure what should not be compiled in runtime. Probably there are some deprecated `RepositoryImpl`s?

Comment: @LouisGo There are only one ```RepositoryImpl``` that can will be used in the whole application's lifecycle, so my boss want it to be determined before runtime. However, it is actually totally valid to configure what to use at config/build time. So i think it might be best to test all ```RepositoryImpl``` well(concretely, i use gtest typed test)

Comment: Take your unit test as an application using `DummyRepository` as well. It's not just one implementation. You have production and testing applications and they use different implementations.

Comment: @LouisGo and that really leads me to runtime configuration solution which adopted by now

Comment: IMHO, you know the issue, but you need to let your boss to know this issue as well. Either drop tests, sacrifice compile time, or your boss had a better solution in his/her mind.